# how to use map() function with a function without return value in python

Tags: python

I guess map function is a value-returning function, but how could I use it with a function that return nothing, for example:

```
class People:
    member = ''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.member = name

    def addPerson(self, member):
        self.member += member

b = People("Jack")

map(b.addPerson, ['Michale','Joe'])
```

And what I want is :

```py
b.member == 'JackMichaleJoe'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. The point of map is to perform a *conversion* of the input (not an in-place mutation). Using map (or comprehensions) for side-effects is bad style and makes for confusing code.

What you do is a normal for loop:

```py
for person in ['Michale','Joe']: b.addPerson(person)
```

Incidentally, your

> ```
> member = ''
> ```

is at best useless and at worst actively harmful. It defines a *class attribute* `member` which is not of any use because it's shadowed by the *instance attribute* of the same name.

and

> ```
> def addPerson(self, member):
>     self.member += member
> ```

while this sort of thing can be useful, Python developers generally avoid them unless they're actually useful / necessary. Here, I don't personally feel this method pulls its weight. And the naming is not conventional, it should be `add_person`.

Comment: Many thanks to you. I just take an example. Actually, the reason why i want to use map function is I want to pass two lists as parameters of a function, which takes two parameters and returns nothing. So how could I use for loop to solve it.

Comment: You have two lists, and you want to "pair" list items in order to pass them to a function? While `map` can do that for convenience you'd normally use `zip`: `for a, b in zip(lista, listb): call_func(a, b)`.